# How can I merge my changes to a Tag in Git?

Tags: git, version-control

I am on Master Branch as seen above:

```
koraytugay$ git branch -a
  EBT-7869
  ebt-7911-cross-client
* master
```

And I have 5 changes but I want to merge only 2 of the files into a different tag.

```
koraytugay$ git tag
3.1.8
3.2.0
```

How can I merge only 2 files (Lets say A.java and B.java) to 3.2.0 tag?

Comment: Why don't you first commit these two files and then merge the new commit to the tag?

Comment: @Juan how can I do that?

Comment: In git, a tag identifies one (single) commit and *should* never be changed to identify any other commit (it's not impossible to do, it's just generally a bad idea).  And, in git, merging generally results in a new commit (ignoring "fast forward" merges): you merge *from* some commit/branch to produce a new commit on the current branch.  It's not clear what you mean by "merge *to*" something, and you probably should not move a tag, but you might make a new tag for your new commit (which might go on a branch named "branch3.2" or some such).

Comment: @torek I am very new to git as well. We have this version 3.2.0 released with a minor bug. I fixed the bug in master branch but we need the fix in 3.2.0 as well.

Comment: It makes more sense to say that the update will create "version 3.2.1" (then versions on the "3.2" branch would be numbered "3.2.x" for some x).  Otherwise, someone has "broken version 3.2.0" and someone else has "corrected version 3.2.0" so now you really have "3.2.0.0" and "3.2.0.1", and so on.  (In other words, pick a numbering scheme and stick to it, don't make two versions with the *same* number.)

Comment: @torek: 4 secs faster than me :-)

Comment: @KorayTugay I though you were asking about how to merge two out of five files somewhere else, I just understood that the main point is to merge in the actual tag. If you merge, as torek said a new commit would be created, but the tag would still be pointing to the previous commit. I think with an interactive rebase you could squash the new commit into the one where the tag is placed, but I am not 100% sure about this being a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out a new branch based on 3.2.0, merge the update, and tag the merge as 3.2.1

```
$ git checkout -b bugfix 3.2.0
$ git checkout master A.java B.java
$ git add A.java B.java
$ git commit
$ git tag 3.2.1
```

When you commit, make sure you describe what the changes are and why they are being made).

You might need to replace the checkout of `A.java` and `B.java` with something more complicated (like using `git cherry-pick`) depending on what exactly you need to bring in from `master`.